# How to snapshot a bucket without shutting down a service?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a service using GCS to store data, and I am working on a backup plan. Currently, I am using Storage Transfer Service to transfer that data to the backup bucket. My problem is I want the backup bucket data be consistent with other data backups, so I just want a snapshot at the time backup started without shutting down my service.

So my questions would be:
1. What happens if the service write new data or update existing data (create a new version) into the source bucket during the transfer? Will the new records be transferred to the sink bucket?
2. My problem is I don't want any new records or new version created after the backup timestamp to be in the sink bucket. Is this even possible? Is there a practical solution for this or alternative solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid having objects written after the backup start timestamp you'll need to write code to check the object's timestamp before backing it up -- or find a piece of backup software that can do that.